# keep hidden div id on browser refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have divs set to 100% height and have them showing and hiding with a combination of css and jquery.

All works perfectly until I am on index.html#panel(x) and refresh my browser. Then it converts back to a messy scroll function.

Here's the crux: Is there a better way to set this up? It seems like all I'm trying to do is show and hide divs, but I need to be able to refresh the index.html#panel(x) and have it all work seamlessly.

Please let it be known that I am not a jquery or javascript savant, so please be kind when you chastise how dumb I am.

I've spent too many sleepless night trying to get this functionality right and need some help. Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">

html, body {
height:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;

}

.nav {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left:0;
z-index:100;

}

.container_main {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left:0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

#panel1, #panel2, #panel3, #panel4, #home  {
max-width: 680px;
height: 100%;
margin:auto;
}

#panel1, #panel2, #panel3, #panel4  {
display:none;
}

#panel1:target{
display:block;
}

#panel2:target{
display:block;
}

#panel3:target{
display:block;
}

#panel4:target{
display:block;
}


</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".toggle").click(function(){
    $("#home").hide();
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="nav">
<a class="toggle" href="#panel1">Panel1</a><br>
<a class="toggle" href="#panel2">Panel2</a><br>
<a class="toggle" href="#panel3">Panel3</a><br>
<a class="toggle" href="#panel4">Panel4</a>
</div>

<div class="container_main">
<div id="home" style="background-color:#678993;">Minneapolis</div>
<div id="panel1" style="background-color:#678993;">Minneapolis</div>
<div id="panel2" style="background-color:#cccccc;">LALA</div>
<div id="panel3" style="background-color:#aaaaaa;">St Paul</div>
<div id="panel4" style="background-color:#DB62A1;">SF</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The simpler, most cross-browser solution the better, Thanks in advance!

Comment: panel1 and home same content ? dont do this use panel1 like home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you start your page with a hash `#panel4` it will not call the `.click()` event and will not hide your `#home` div.

You have to check if there's a hash in your url and remove the `#home` div on document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggle").click(function(){
        $("#home").hide();
    });

    if(window.location.hash) {
        // Fragment exists
        $("#home").hide();
    }
});
```

See [Window Location hash](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Check at the document ready if existing hash corresponding at panel value:

```
$(function() {
    var hash = location.hash.substr(1);
    if($.inArray(hash, [ "panel1", "panel2", "panelx" ])) {
        $("#home").hide();
    }

    $(".toggle").on('click', function(){
        $("#home").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">

html, body {
height:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;

}

.nav {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left:0;
z-index:100;

}

.container_main {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left:0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

#panel1, #panel2, #panel3, #panel4  {
max-width: 680px;
height: 100%;
margin:auto;
}

#panel2, #panel3, #panel4  {
display:none;
}

#panel1:target{
display:block;
}

#panel2:target{
display:block;
}

#panel3:target{
display:block;
}

#panel4:target{
display:block;
}


</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clean_hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    if(clean_hash && clean_hash!='panel1'){
        $('#panel1').hide();
        $('#'+clean_hash).show();
    }
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="nav">
<a class="toggle" href="#panel1">Panel1</a><br>
<a class="toggle" href="#panel2">Panel2</a><br>
<a class="toggle" href="#panel3">Panel3</a><br>
<a class="toggle" href="#panel4">Panel4</a>
</div>

<div class="container_main">
<div id="panel1" style="background-color:#678993;">Minneapolis</div>
<div id="panel2" style="background-color:#cccccc;">LALA</div>
<div id="panel3" style="background-color:#aaaaaa;">St Paul</div>
<div id="panel4" style="background-color:#DB62A1;">SF</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

i have remove #home and detect if hash is present to show panel

Comment: nanndoj this works perfectly! can you explain to me why it works though? why wouldnt the index.html#panel4 just continue to display:none the panels in the css?

Comment: benjamin, the reason I had the duplicate home and panel1 was to be able to show the first panel on page load. with your update, it seems to work within itself, but the first page doesnt show when you just go to index.html

id really like to try your solution too, as it looks very promising.

THANKS TO ALL OF YOU FOR YOUR HELP!

Comment: Did you see this change `#panel2, #panel3, #panel4  {display:none;}` ? By default panel1 is show